# How to connect JDBC to Microsoft SQL Server in JMeter?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jmeter

How to connect JDBC to Microsoft SQL Server so that I can test my SQL Server database in JMeter.

I am using Apache Jmeter 2.13. I have put the sqljdbc4.jar file in JMeter/lib folder. I also created a very simple database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio where my server name is localhost and I have used windows authentication to connect to my server. Then in JMeter I have used the following properties in JDBC Connection Configuration :

```
Database URL:jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=JmeterTestDatabase.
JDBC Driver Class:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.
Username:ABC-PC\ABC.
Password: Somepassword.
```

When I run the test I get the following error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user
>   'ABC-PC\ABC'. ClientConnectionId:7c9e308b-1bdc-4513-8386-5bc51f249029

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log in failed is a clear message we are seeing , please check it once again.

TRY this as well, I have given below by assuming username as "ABC-PC\ABC" and password as "Somepassword" change accordingly.

Database URL:jdbc:sqlserver://ABC-PC\ABC/Somepassword@localhost:1433;DatabaseName=JmeterTestDatabase.
JDBC Driver Class:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.

Comment: I tried as you told, but same error as Log in failed. Just to inform you, when I choose windows authentication to connect to my server in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, by default the ' connect to server ' window only shows username as "ABC-PC\ABC", the password field is empty.

Comment: i suspect ABC-PC\ABC is a username ?  please find what is correct username and password for this .  acording  to the naming convention ABC-PC is computer name and ABC is user name.

Comment: I have tried with ABC. But no luck. Isn't it the username and password that I use to log in to my windows after starting the computer? Or do I need to search for a different username and password?

Comment: Also Try ... jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;integratedSecurity=true;

Comment: Thank you, I have solved my problem. I visited the link you shared. Then created my own server authentication credentials in SSMS from New Login. It solved my problem.

Comment: I am glad that it helped . Thank You.